# Use scanf() with a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to pass an address as an argument to a process for an exercise. It doesn't work so I made this simple example to find what is wrong:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  int newCounter = 0; // I want to get the value of this using its address
  int *address; // The pointer
  printf("%p\n", &newCounter); // Printing the address
  scanf("%p", address); // We insert the address manually
  printf("%d\n", *address);
}
```

When I'm running this program I get a message `Segmentation fault: 11` after inserting the address of `newCounter` manually and pressing Enter, does someone know what is wrong with this code?

Comment: A simple but important question: **Did you ever try compiling that with full warnings?** Because I expect even MSVC++ to complain really loudly.

Comment: actually this line: scanf("%p", address); is trying to place an address value where the variable address points,  currently is does not point to any specific thing.  however, if you want to change the value in the address variable then use: scanf("%p", &address);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `scanf()`, you must pass a pointer to where you want the result to be stored. You should have this:

```
scanf("%p", &address);
```

(Note the use of `&`). You are getting a segfault because `scanf()` assumes that the argument you passed is a pointer to a valid memory location where the result can be stored.

Also, `scanf()` can only read `void *` pointers - you need to change the declaration of `address` to be a `void *`:

```
void *address; // The pointer
```

And pay attention to this:

```
printf("%d\n", *address);
```

How will you make sure that the address you entered is valid? This will most likely crash.

Comment: BTW: It can crash even before that `printf`, if the implementation is allergic to invalid non-null pointers. Which is not unreasonable.